# How do you play a local flv video file in flex mobile project?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, flash-builder

Good afternoon, 
I trying to play a flv file in a flex mobile (flex 4.6) The files will all be locally stored and on the device. Would it be better to use the video  even if it is not supported or can i use a movieClip? I am going to try and fade out a picture and then play the video with out any user controls and then fade back to the picture. The this will all be on a tablet. I am using Flash Builder 4.6. If I can use a movieClip would someone please give me a tutorial or a snippet of code on how to load a local flv file into it. 
Thanks for you help!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help you:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/video_flex.html

Comment: I also used this resource successfully, but do you have an idea about how to stop the video from playing automatically?