# How to play Video on air mobile app?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air, flash-builder

Good afternoon,
I am trying to get and air application to play a video smoothly on a android device. I am using flex 4.6.0 and flash builder 4.6. 
Does anyone know of any working examples that play local video (videos that are built into the app) and are high quality that doesn't stutter? Should I be building all of my app in as3 and not be using flex? What are people using to show high quality videos in air mobile projects? I am building this for the eee transformer prime. Any time i play a video throw my app even if it using stage video I is jumpy and stutters if i play it just on the tablet it works fine. Are other people running into the same problems I'm running into? (the question bellow show some of the problems)

[How do you play a local flv video file in flex mobile project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930868/how-do-you-play-a-local-flv-video-file-in-flex-mobile-project)

[How to play videos on a android tablet in with adobe air mobile with out them being choppy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024618/how-to-play-videos-on-a-andriod-tablet-in-with-adobe-air-mobile-with-out-them-be)

[Adobe air mobile why does the stage flickers when starting a video a stageVideo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119027/adobe-air-mobile-why-does-the-stage-flickers-when-starting-a-video-a-stagevideo)

So my question is this is there any working examples of large videos playing on a mobile application? (what i mean by large video is 16mb files. 720p h.264 files) 
Thanks for any help i have bin trying to salve this for weeks and haven't bin able to if i could put a bounty on this i would. 
Thank for reading,
Justin

Comment: "if i play it just on the tablet it works fine." I don't understand what this means.  How do you play it just on the tablet?  Are you referring to the built in video player application?  Or something different?

Comment: The tablet has a built in video player that if you pick a file in the Files Manager system it will play the video. It will play the video smoother throw this app then if i create a stageVideo and then grab the video from that same location and it plays way worse throw the app with the stageView (the video is more jumpy and don't play smoothly at all and flickers when loading) Kind of strange. When you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://polygeek.com/4299_air-mobile_playing-youtube-videos-in-your-air-mobile-apps) is the link for playing youTube videos in AIR mobile apps, but you can change the 
video url path. hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your video file into .swf format then load it through swfloader. I have already try with thie and it is working. Thank you